# Play! framework with Ebean: PersistenceException

Tags: java, jpa, web, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a `Topic` class which extends `Model`.
creating the first record of table topics is fine, but it is failing to create another record:

> [PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR:
>   duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_topics"\n Detail:
>   Key (id)=(1) already exists.]]

the exception occur of course at this line:

```
topic.save();
```

this is weird because:

1. it worked before without a problem.
2. the attribute `id` is defined with the a annotation `@Id` which suppose to **auto increment** to the next value, but I get exception about **duplicate id**.

what should I do to solve this problem?

**class `Model` (not all of course, only what's relevant)**:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "topics")
public class Topic extends Model {
@Id
public long id;
public String title;
public String content;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "forumId")
public Forum forum;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
public User user;
public Date date;

public static void create(Topic topic) {
    topic.save();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your model and the code which saves it? Do you use fixtures? What is your play version and OS? @Id is not sufficient, maybe you need a Sequence: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated . I used Identity.

Comment: I added the code of `Topic` class. I don't what is fixtures.
I'm using Play! 2.0 under linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. when I changed back the access modifier of `id` to `protected` it worked again. weird, but now it works perfectly.

explanation?